# How To Open and Read a File of Type FileField in Django?

Tags: python, django, file

I am trying to open a file that would be uploaded through the django FileField attribute. I also want to read the contents of the file and output it. But when I do open(obj.file), it gives me an error that read "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FieldFile" So, I am not sure how to get around this! I also tried using obj.file.read(),this does the job, but it gives these "\n" "\r" characters in the output.

This is my views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ReaderForm

def HomePage(request):
    text = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ReaderForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            file = form.cleaned_data.get('file')
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.file = file
            obj.save()

            f = open(obj.file, "r")
            print(f.read())

    else:
        form = ReaderForm()
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "text": text
    }
    return render(request, "reader/home.html", context)
```

This is models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone



class Reader(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_uploaded']
        verbose_name_plural = "Reader"
```

This is my template file (home.html)

```html
{% extends 'reader/base.html' %}


{% block head %}
    <title>File Reader</title>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    <h1>File Reader</h1>

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    {% if not text == None %}
        <p>{{ text }}</p>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

And lastly, forms.py

```py
from .models import Reader
from django import forms


class ReaderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reader
        fields = ['file']
```

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: In your template also use `{% if text %}` instead `{% if not text == None %}`. And add `action attribute` to your html form: `action="/your-name/"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `FieldFile` object includes its own open.  Instead of:

```py
f = open(obj.file,'r')
```

Do this:

```py
f = obj.file.open('r')
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, but do you have any way to preserve the line breaks and spaces. Because the output just goes on without any line breaks. No spaces

Comment: No one should be manipulating the content in any way.  You should be able to get lines by doing `lines = obj.file.open('r').readlines()` or `lines = obj.file.open('r').read().splitlines()`.

Comment: I'll wager you're printing the results to a web page.  If so, it's the web browser that's removing the lines and spaces.  You can put it inside `<pre>` tags.

Comment: the splitlines() and the readlines() just give the output in a list. But you are right. I am printing the results to a webpage. The ```<pre>``` tags work! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[**`FileField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#using-files-in-models) ([Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#using-files-in-models)) has a `path` property.

So you can do:

```
f = open(obj.file.path, "r")
print(f.read())
```

As suggested in the comments, using the context manager:

```
with open(obj.file.path, "r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

---

We can just use `read()` or `readlines()` to get the content of file:

```
content = obj.file.read()
lines = obj.file.readlines()
```

[**`The File object`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#the-file-object), [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#the-file-object) says:

> In addition to the listed methods, **File** exposes the following
> attributes and methods of its **file** object: **encoding, fileno, flush,**
> **isatty, newlines, read, readinto, readline, readlines, seek, tell,**
> **truncate, write, writelines, readable(), writable(),** and **seekable()**.

Comment: Thank you! your solution worked too. But do you have any way to preserve line breaks and spaces? Because the output just goes on without any spaces and line breaks.

Comment: Also, the action attribute just takes me to a different page. And thanks for your suggestion on {% if text %}. That reduced my code a bit.

Comment: The answer could be improved by using a context manager (i.e. `with`).